# Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Contact'

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-services

**detail.component.ts**

```ts
contact: Contact;
constructor( private contactService: LocalStorageService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.contact = this.contactService
    .getContact(815);
}
```

**contact.service.ts**

```ts
getContact(id: number) {
    var contact = 
    JSON.parse(LocalStorage.getItem("contacts")).filter((cntct) => { 
      return cntct.id == id 
    });
}
```

> Error: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Contact'.

here, in the url I have  `/detail/"clicked-contacts-id-number"`

I want to fetch the contact data of that contact's id.

Comment: you should return contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return the Contact. You can simplify your code like this

```
getContact(id: number) {
  return JSON.parse(LocalStorage.getItem("contacts")).filter((cntct) => { 
      return cntct.id == id });
}
```

Comment: thank you but still while in html component {{contact.name}} doesnt disply anything.

Comment: <p>{{contact.name}}</p>

Comment: @OmPatel It is also possible that the data you are returning is null that's why. try to do an *ngIf="contact" in your template to check if it is not null

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning contact from your get contact method

```
getContact(id: number) {
    var contact = 
JSON.parse(LocalStorage.getItem("contacts")).filter((cntct) => { return 
cntct.id == id });
return contact //add this line
}
```

Comment: thank you but still while in html component {{contact.name}} doesnt disply anything.

Comment: does a contact with id 815 exists?
also filter method will return an array.make sure you loop over that

Answer (score 0):

you haven't defined the return type of getContact() func in contact.service.ts.

try with this..

getContact(id: number): Contact {